# i want to remove default box border of ajax pie chat

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, rdlc

I want to remove default box border of ajax pie chart which is not require for me can any one help me out form this issue.

[image]

Comment: can i edit the code which i highlighted in image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it, using ID selector and !important

```
#MainContent_PieChart1__ParentDiv{
    border: none !important;
}
```

or using ID + Attribute selector

```
#MainContent_PieChart1__ParentDiv[style]{
    border: none !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks hitesh for quick response. can you please where to find id sector

Comment: right click on the element and select inspect element